# Copy Sharepoint folder and keep permissions

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, robocopy

I've been researching this for a bit and I've found that copying a Sharepoint folder doesn't actually keep the permissions intact.

I've tried mapping the Sharepoint folder to X:\ and then using Robocopy with this command:

```
Robocopy "X:\SharepointFolder\Bob Dylan" "X:\SharepointFolder\John Lennon" /E /SEC
```

This copies the folders, but the permissions isn't kept anyway. Actually I get this error message in the cmd window saying

```
          New Dir          0    X:\SharepointFolder\Bob Dylan\Documents\
2011/06/01 11:32:28 ERROR 1 (0x00000001) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Di
rectory X:\SharepointFolder\Bob Dylan\Documents\
Incorrect function.
```

The thing is, is my syntax incorrect or is it impossible to copy folder permissions in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying a folder via WebDAV won't copy any meta data set on the folder. Therefor permissions won't be copied as well.

Comment: Aha, which explains everything. Is there not any way of doing this then?  Seems kinda hopeless, considering how extensive people use Sharepoint.

Comment: you could write a powershell script. Take a look at `SPFolder.CopyTo()`. But with this method you have to manually copy the permissions...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Publishing Features turned on, check out the Manage Content and Structure Report.  I think it will allow you to move things around within a site collection and perserve your metadata and security.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error.  I was using mapped drives to copy data to SharePoint.  I found that my xml file on the SharePoint mapped drive (destination) was applied with encryption attributes recently applied to my pc (source).

I am still looking for a way to use robocopy or powershell to remove the encryption from the destination file programatically.

To manually remove the attribute, navigate to the mapped drive, go to properties of the xml file, at the bottom in Attributes click Advanced, uncheck 'Encrypt contents..', apply.

(**For those not sure how to see the attributes)
Open explorer for your mapped drive, on the column header bar right click and choose attributes.  You can see the security applied.  E is encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I am in developing small Batch File to get Access Control List based on CMD

```
net user USERID /domain [enter]
```

I am welcome to everybody have idea to APPLY access permission of SharePoint within CMD. Thank you in advanced. :)